# Ant handle Target not found

Tags: ant

I have created an ant project which has some targets inside. One target is called **info**, which displays all available targets. This target is set as the default:

```
<project name="XXX" basedir="." default="info">
```

Now I want this target to be called in case of target not found:

```
Target "infp" does not exist in the project "XXX"
```

I need this in case the user calls a target that doesn't exist. Then I want the info to be displayed, so that he sees all the available options.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANT does not support this functionality. The "default" target is called if no target is specified on the command line.

Instead I would suggest making your build self describing and teaching your users about ANT
's **-p** option.

## Example

The following build file:

```
<project name="demo" default="welcome">

    <description>
    The purpose of this build file is to explain how one
    can make an ANT file self describing
    </description>

    <target name="welcome" description="Print a hello world message">
        <echo message="hello world"/>
    </target>

    <target name="do-somthing" description="Print a dummy message">
        <echo message="hello world"/>
    </target>

    <target name="do-somthing-silent">
        <echo message="hello world"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Can describe itself as follows:

```
$ ant -p
Buildfile: /home/mark/build.xml

    The purpose of this build file is to explain how one 
    can make an ANT file self describing

Main targets:

 do-somthing  Print a dummy message
 welcome      Print a hello world message
Default target: welcome
```